# What determines the "special" color of the status bar in SpringBoard?

Tags: ios, springboard

I've noticed that at various times, the status bar in SpringBoard will occasionally change colors. When using the Voice Memos app on iPhone, it will be red. While in a call, it's green. Using personal hotspot, I'm seeing a blue.

Is there any significance to the colors, or is this a totally arbitrary choice by Apple?

Comment: Red shows up when the mic is in use; Apple uses this to warn that an app could be monitoring you without your knowledge. I expect the others are arbitrary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I have seen, the color is supposed to tell you a little bit about what is going on, or what app is active.

**Voice Memos is red**, which is the color typically used for 'Recording'.
**Calls are green**, which is the color of the Phone app's icon and is used in several places in the app (e.g., the Accept button).
**AirPlay is blue**, which is the color that Apple typically associates with both wireless and music (AirPort and Bluetooth logos are blue, iTunes' icon is blue, the Remote app's icon is blue).
**Personal hotspot is blue**, which again is the color of 'wireless'.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is nothing more to it than using colours that resemble the App icons for each function.  So phonecalls=green (green call icon), recording=red (Red for generic recording as used everywhere, and the icons design used to be red until it went blue...), and hotspot=blue(think Safari/Mail and other "internet" related icons colours, and also it's just different to the others and completes the RGB colour scheme...)